# Обход всех экземпляров всех наследников класса С++

Tags: c++, наследование

Здравствуйте!  Предположим есть некий класс

```
class Parent
{

protected:

    static Parent *Head_ptr;
    static Parent *Tail_ptr;
    Parent *NextObject_ptr;

    virtual void SomeVirtualMethod(void){}

    static void AllSomeVirtualMethods(void)
    {
        Parent *CurrentObject_ptr = Parent::Head_ptr;

        while (CurrentObject_ptr != NULL)
        {
            CurrentObject_ptr->SomeVirtualMethod();
            CurrentObject_ptr = CurrentObject_ptr->NextObject_ptr;
        }
    }

public:

    Parent()
    {
        if (Parent::Head_ptr == NULL)
        {
            Parent::Head_ptr = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Tail_ptr->NextObject_ptr = this;
            this->NextObject_ptr = NULL;
        }

        Parent::Tail_ptr = this;
    }
};
```

Если создавать экземпляры класса Parent, то по задумке указатель на каждый добавленный объект записывается в предыдущем объекте. Таким образом, осуществляется вызов всех методов созданных объектов данного класса по сформированному списку.

Однако, задача усложняется. Мне необходимо перебирать все объекты каждого из унаследованных от Parent классов.

Фактически, мне нужен следующий порядок вызова виртуальных функций SomeVirtualMethod. По очереди вызываются виртуальные методы всех объектов первого унаследованного класса, далее по очереди вызываются виртуальные методы всех объектов второго унаследованного класса и так для всех унаследованных классов. Как лучше реализовать такой способ обхода?

Так же меня интересует в целом как обходить именно унаследованные классы а не их объекты.  К примеру считать из каждого наследованного класса значение статической переменной унаследованной от базового класса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Могу предложить включить RTTI. После этого выполняем первичный перебор *всех* объектов и заносим их в `std::multimap<std::type_info, Parent*>` (то есть группируем указатели на объекты по общему фактическому типу дочернего класса; и да, цикл `while` можно переписать на `for`):

```
static void AllSomeVirtualMethods(void)
{
    std::multimap<std::type_index, Parent*> perTypeGrouping;
    for(
        Parent *CurrentObject_ptr = Parent::Head_ptr;
        CurrentObject_ptr != NULL;
        CurrentObject_ptr = CurrentObject_ptr->NextObject_ptr
    )
    {
        perTypeGrouping.insert(
            std::type_index(typeid(*CurrentObject_ptr)),
            CurrentObject_ptr
        );
    }
}
```

После этого мы проходим уже по `multimap`-у. Так как ассоциативный массив гарантирует упорядоченность по ключу, то все объекты одного фактического класса окажутся по соседству.

```
for(
    std::multimap<std::type_index, Parent*>::iterator entry = perTypeGrouping.begin(),
    entry != perTypeGrouping.end();
    ++entry
)
    entry->second->SomeVirtualMethod();
```

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ! А есть ли способ реализовать данную задачу без использования RTTI и std ? Можно ли создать отдельный список и помещать туда указатели на первые созданные объекты каждого из наследников, а затем по цепочке начиная с первого объекта проходить все объекты каждого из наследников?